# Unable to start the daemon process, How do I update Gradle Classpath for "Insert Project Name"

Tags: eclipse, gradle, daemon

When I click on details it shows this:

Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error: Could not find or load main class =

Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip'.

---

I have Eclipse 4.4.1 I know I have the gradle plugin, I'm not sure how to reinstall it. I just don't know what to edit in order for it to run again. 
Please help me I'm getting tired of Eclipse and all of their ridiculous addons and configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your project you have the eclipse plugin applied?

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html